# dll auto image-base

Tags: visual-c++, dll

is there an equivalent option line --enable-auto-image-base (gcc/cygwin) in vc++ to automatically set a default image-base address of a DLL?

or does someone know the common practise to calculate unique base address and specify it with /BASE?

I'm compiling many simple DLLs from c source files inside an batch,
and all DLLs have the same base address of 0x1000...

Answer (score 0):

You can use "`editbin /rebase`" or the `rebase` command to rebase a list of DLLs.